# Ruby on Rails - Parent object to create with child object attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a parent object that has a polymorphic-has_many association with a child. The child does not have any backward-relation to its parent. It only has a polymorphic relation with itself. Using AJAX I would like to send the parent object up. I would like for the parent object to include the child and create the child along-side itself in the create section of the parent controller. The code however is not liking something that I am doing and is failing. I am not sure if this is a problem with naming-convention (IE: the name of the object being passed to rails) or a problem with the linking of the relationships between the models.

```
Parent Model:

    has_many :tags, :as => :taggable

Tag Model:

    belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
```

Object passed to attempt create:

```
Parent:
 Parent_attributes
 tagables_attributes
  [0]
   'content'
  [1]
   'content'
  ...
```

I have tried passing in the "tabables_attributes" with many different similar names. As I said, I'm not sure if that was the problem-part or not. Perhaps it is the object name that is wrong, or perhaps it is a model problem?

```
  Tag:

  t.text :content
  t.integer :taggable_id
  t.string :taggable_type
```

Please let me know any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your parent model.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Perfect, so much time spent looking for one little line. haha